# Parameter error in Azure worker role instance in server explorer

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, azure, azure-worker-roles

I have an Azure worker role deployed. I wanted to attach remote debugger in it. But I cannot select the Azure worker role instance from the server explorer. I am getting the error extensionconfiguration null. see attached screenshot.

[image]
[image]

The closest reference I got was another link that states the same problem.

[reference link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/274684/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-extensionconfi.html)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is the issue for the VS tool. And it has been traced by Microsoft VS team.

According to this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/274684/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-extensionconfi.html), it has beed fixed with 15.8 release version. If it is released, you could try it again.

> Thank you for your feedback! We have fixed the problem in the **upcoming 15.8 release.** Thank you for helping us build a better Visual Studio!